# What happened to mate-terminal?

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, profile, mate-desktop

I did apt-get dist-upgrade to my Kali (rolling) and suddenly mate-terminal (1.14.0-1) went mad. No more transparent backgrounds but what really made me rip my shorts was the seeming inability to bring up my tabs from pre-made profile. One profile works, one does not.

What's up with that.

Comment: Looks like the transparent background actually works in dual monitor setup but only when another app is active in the second display.

Comment: Looks like I can open all the tabs in pre-made profile if I use "File | Open Tab" instead of "File | Open Terminal".

Answer (score 0):

If I ignore the transparency issue I got mate-terminal finally working by making my old profiles more accurate. Apparently mate-terminal now employs more stricter error checking mechanism and no longer work with undefined profile names ie. --tab-with-profile=Default only works in one profile (the first one.) Your next profile must be named differently (Default2 or for instance "Servers" like in my example below) and it must reflect in the new profile custom command. example: `mate-terminal --tab-with-profile=Servers -t "server1" -e "ssh root@server1.domain.com -t screen -dRRS main" --tab-with-profile=Servers -t "server2" -e "ssh root@server2.domain.com -t screen -dRRS main"` Using more precise Profile definitions and custom commands I can ones again get all my 100 or so Tabs in order up and re-connected with a click of a button :)